# offsetting browser native smooth scroll via anchor links

Tags: javascript, html, css, offset, smooth-scrolling

My document is using browser-native smooth scroll behavior defined via CSS (and not javascript) and anchor links to scroll down to a specified part of the page when clicked on.

This works fine except that the top of the page the anchors are located at end up hidden underneath the sticky nav bar that is fixed to the top of the screen after the animated scroll has finished.  I therefore need to offset the scroll's destination Y coordinate.

Example (when you click):

```css
@media ( prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference ) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
main {
    margin: 4rem 1rem 120vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>Nav Bar</nav>

<main>
  <a href="#example">Example Anchor Link</a>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <p id="example">Scroll Target</p>
</main>
```

Is there a way to offset the scroll target so that it's not covered up by the nav bar?  I don't think there is a javascript event that fires when the browser's scroll animation has completed.  I also haven't seen a way to customize the browser's animation duration.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question...

The answer is pretty simple, you can always give some padding top to the target element, in this case for instance 60px of padding  since the nav bar is 50px in height. This will act as an offset.

```css
@media ( prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference ) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
main {
    margin: 4rem 1rem 120vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>Nav Bar</nav>

<main>
  <a href="#example">Example Anchor Link</a>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <p id="example" style="padding-top: 60px;">Scroll Target</p>
</main>
```